# How to setup EWS permission to delete items?

Tags: outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

Posting a query to EWS delete an email returns an error: "The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties"

However, posting the same query from inside an add-in works. All my research point to this being a permission issue. But I have not been able to confirm it. Is there setting that will allow third-party code to move or delete emails?

Here the query to delete an email:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:DeleteItem DeleteType="MoveToDeletedItems" AffectedTaskOccurrences="AllOccurrences" SendMeetingCancellations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
        <m:ItemIds>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADE2NjQyMjVlLWNhY2UtNDNiMS04MzgxLWZiNzEyNzA0NDgwNQBGAAAAAACLt5QBAQ/GRYv+vEXkY5vLBwA6ksGFFTICTbjFW6e9FfRGAAAAAAEMAAA6ksGFFTICTbjFW6e9FfRGAAA//84oAAA=" />
        </m:ItemIds>
      </m:DeleteItem>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What leads you to think it's a permission issue? How are you authenticating, as the mailbox owner or someone else (delegate, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there setting that will allow third-party code to move or delete emails?

No it depends on the permissions on the Containing folder or Mailbox, I would suggest you look at security context the Addin is running under. You might also want to try a Soft or HardDelete rather then doing a MoveToDeleteItems.